# Expedited review has still not been approved

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I recently needed to urgently submit an app update to resolve a critical bug. Of course, I requested an expedited review. The problem is that it is now 4 days later and my update has still not been approved.

Accidentally, I requested the expedited review before I uploaded and submitted the binary (only a difference of about 10 minutes) and I was wondering if this could have invalidated the expedited request?

Should I resend the request, or just wait? My initial app was approved in 3 days. How long should I expect an expedited review to take?

Comment: Less than 24 hours for us this past weekend... just one data point. But, we did have a timely event, not a critical bug. (coverage in a major newspaper for today.)

Comment: So you requested an expedited review and it was approved within 24 hours? Sounds like I should probably resend the request then.

Comment: Sorta. Requested the expedited review Friday around 4pm. Expedited request was approved, I think Sunday morning. App was reviewed and approved Sunday evening. But, this was for a time sensitive issue, not a critical bug. That might make a difference.

Comment: I'm changing my comment to an answer here because I re-read the question, the 10 minute "mistake" didn't matter for us!

Comment: You're welcome, and good luck with. 4 days seems like a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Requested an expedited review Friday around 4pm. Expedited request was approved, I think Sunday morning. App was reviewed and approved Sunday evening. Tthis was for a time sensitive issue, not a critical bug. That might make a difference.

And, like you, I was initially confused by the new iTunesConnect UI. I had thought I had submitted the app for review but I hadn't. So, just like you, about 10 minutes elapsed between submitting the expedite request and actually submitting the app for review.

So I don't think you need to make another request, at least not because of the order of your actions.

Comment: Just to let you know, I resent the expedited review request and within about 2 hours my app update has been approved. I guess there must have been an issue the first time.